# Usage of React Native Debugger with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-debugger

To setup React Native debugger we have to declare a composer like this:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
  rootReducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)
```

But when using with typescript TS Compiler says: `Cannot find name 'window'.ts(2304)`

Already tried changing the key `lib` in `tsconfig.json` to this:

```
"lib": ["es6", "DOM"]
```

But the error changes to:

```
Property '__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Is it your project `React Native`? if yes, you don't need to setup it like this, just use it, the React Native Debugger catch it.

Comment: AmerLLicA thank you. It worked! The documentation must be outdated because it says that this is needed.

Comment: I'm happy that it helps you. I leave an answer for documentation. please mark it as the correct answer to other future visitors. Also, I leave an upvote to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, *React Native Debugger* doesn't need to setup. Just use `Redux` and *React Native Debugger* will catch your state.

Using `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` need to write `window. __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` and the `window` object is just for browswer.